# Настройка редактора в git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, macos, git-commit

Не получается на macbook os monterey 12.04 изменить стандартные настройки в git. Не удобно пользоваться редактором vi, поэтому решил попробовать изменить в настройках на редактор vs code. Для этого использую команду

```
git config --global core.editor '/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app -w'
```

Выдает ошибку

```
warning: core.editor has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change core.editor.
```

Comment: пробовал, тоже самое пишет

Comment: а что у вас там за параметр стоит? по логике вам в кавычках нужно указывать программу которую хотите использовать и больше ничего

Comment: что пробовал???

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [документации](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-C:-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) команда должна быть:

```bash
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```